# Selenium webdriver java query

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Please provide me the automation script for the following select country drop down box.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note this site isn't intended as a code writing service. Could you include what you've tried thus far?

Comment: Could you please add some code from your side and explain the problem you are facing.  Also try to find something similar in a website which is open to all rather accessible to you only. Also mention the versions of each library you are using.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

You can select drop down values in different way :

1. Visible Text
2. Index
3. Option values

Please find below example using java code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='countries']")));
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("Hungary");
drpCountry.selectByValue("India");
drpCountry.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am unable to generate the automation script for Select country drop down box.

Comment: Please try above code its working I have already verified and its working as expected

Comment: If you are happy then please accept my answer and hit upvote button

Answer (score 0):

```
country=Select(dr.find_element_by_id("country"))

allCountries=country.options

for count in allCountries:
    print(count.text)

country.select_by_visible_text("Japan")
```